# spring boot @ConfigurationProperties: collection without a wrapping object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in my yml i have a list of maps (or a list of objects)

```
topLevel:
  - mapKey1: value1
    mapKey2: value2

  - mapKey1: value3
    mapKey2: value4
```

spring can load it into a static structure when i have an object that keep the nested list (kotlin code):

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
class MyRoot {var topLevel = mutableListOf<MyElement>()}
class MyElement {var mapKey1 = ""; var mapKey2 = ""}
```

but i'm not really interested in the wrapping object `MyRoot`. i care only about the list of `MyElement` objects. can i somehow autowire the list itself without defining the `MyRoot` class?

Comment: Just an idea, never tried it. Instead of `@Component`, try to use `@Bean` in `@Configuration` class to define a bean of type `List<MyElement>`. Like the datasource here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232021/using-configurationproperties-annotation-on-bean-method/43232480

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot 2.1.3 (not sure of the exact version this started working) I was able to do this by doing something like

```
@ConfigurationProperties("topLevel")
@Component
public class MyRoot extends ArrayList<MyElement> {}
```

This doesn't seem to work for Spring Boot 1.5.9